# eureka zuul cannot find my python app registered on eureka

Tags: netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have a python web app, and registered with eureka using restfull api[https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations], and I found it status UP on the eureka web page, but my gateway server(also registered with eureka) can not find it, I call the url "gateway-server-host/myapp-url" and the following response is:

> com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:188)
>   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:163)
>   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:111)

...

> Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not
>   have available server for client: test at
>   com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:483)
>   at
>   com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184)
>   at
>   com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180)

any advise for this problem???

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked over Spring Cloud's `Sidecar` ?

It basically a service over your non-jvm language service (in your case python) and with sidecar service (you have to deploy your python service and the sidecar service on the same host, if I am not mistaken) and you will include in your `Zuul` the endpoint to the sidecar service, which will try to handle things like eureka and such.

You spin up a new spring-boot app, with `@EnableSidecar` annotated, you configure the `health-uri` and `port`

example application.yml

```
server:
  port: 5678
spring:
  application:
    name: sidecar

sidecar:
  port: 8000
  health-uri: http://localhost:8000/health.json
```

You can checkout Spring Cloud's documentation regarding `Sidecar` [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR4/single/spring-cloud.html#_polyglot_support_with_sidecar) for more details how to set it up

Comment: thx for your comment, I decide to write an java-app to test my gateway-server since sidecar need to write java

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Zuul you need to manually register routes. Its okay for them to just include the application name, from Eureka.

Example of Zuul route config:

```
zuul:
 routes:
   application1: /app1/**
   application2: /app2/**
   application3:
     path: /app3/**
     url: http://10.0.8.11:3000/
```

`applicationN` is the name registred in Eureka. The url will be resolved and load balanced automatically. For `app3` the url is manually specified.

Comment: Since the gateway server is based on Zuul, and is no easy to add these config, is there dynamic way to find my app through Eureka?

Comment: Not by default, that I know of. But you can always rebuild your config, eg. update ENV, and then restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Sidecar solves this problem to an extent where your Zuul /routes shows the registered Application Name.

You must have experienced , even if you do not have an actual app and just put any name with a payload following this document - [https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations] , that too gets registered in Eureka as an app.

Comment: This largely seems to be a decent answer. Please move the non-answer part (asking for something and referring, obscurely, to another question) into a comment please.

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, the answer is - because I was not able to put this into a comment. I had to put my answer in first two stanza and then put my query into next two.

Comment: You just wrote a comment. What keeps you from [edit]ing your answer to be ONLY an answer and then move everything non-answerish into a comment like that? You might find this interesting https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: But to access that app through Zuul URL , it must be needing something else. I posted one question for that part.

By the way, do you see a port in Eureka Server dashboard against your registered app ? Can you share your payload please ?